# Cannot figure out how to search for a file on mac os 10.6

Tags: macos, spotlight

I have mac os 10.6. I want to search for a specific file on my machine. I am looking at it in finder, so I know it exists (foo.txt).

I type "foo.txt" into Spotlight, no results.

I type "foo.txt" into a finder window, no results.

I modify the search criteria in the finder window: [name, matches, "foo"]. No results.

How does one search for a specific file on a mac?

Answer (score 4):

Spotlight in Finder excludes system-related directories by default.

Use `mdfind` in Terminal to check if it is actually found by Spotlight, but just excluded from Finder's "user-friendly" results:

```
$ mdfind foo
/private/var/db/foo
```

Needless to say, `/private/var/db` is excluded from Spotlight search results when searching using the GUI

---

Make sure the volume your file is on is included in Spotlight. Check the *Spotlight preference pane*'s exclusions, and `mdutil -s mountpoint`, e.g. `mdutil -s /` for the system disk:

```
$ mdutil -s /
/:
    Indexing enabled.
```

---

You can enable displaying system files by selecting the criteria dropdown (where you select *Kind* etc.), then *Other…*. Search for *System files*, and check it to have it appear in the dropdown list. Whenever you search for system-related files, or want them included, make sure you add this criterion and select *are included*.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use `mdutil` from the command-line, or a third party UI to it without filtering (HoudahSpot comes to mind, but I haven't used it), or use the `locate` command-line tool (and perhaps a GUI for it) once you initialize it using the instructions printed when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be doing things the right way -- Finder is probably best known method for this.

Is there a case-sensitivity option that's turned on?  Is there a "rebuild indexes" type of option available in one of the menus?